# Convert Array to Text File Tab Seperated

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a sample array here

```
[
  [1,2,3,4]
  [5,6,7,8]
  and so on
            ]
```

I have a sample array above how can I create a text file where I can put those
arrays and seperated it by tabs like the sample image below

[image]

a textfile where my arrays are seperated in tabs

I tried this sample code but this code creates a TSV file and only 1st line of data are accepted.

```
var fields = ["field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5"];
var tsv = fields.join("\t");
window.location.href = "data:text/tab-separated-values," + encodeURIComponent(tsv);
```

TYSM

Comment: "*This one is working for me but this is not what I need.*" -- Then what is it that you need? Are you asking how to create the physical `.txt` file?

Comment: Yes sir thats true the sample code above is creating a csv file but only on 1st row

Comment: Sir I edit my post and remove the code. sorry sir please bear with me my only target is to create a textfile based on image above

Comment: Sir I reedit it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `fields` is a two-dimensional array, you need to `join` every array in it with `\t`, then `join` `fields` with `\n`. The easiest way to accomplish this is by using `Array.prototype.map`:

```
var fields = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8]
];
var tsv = fields.map(function(field){
  return field.join("\t");
}).join("\n");
```

Comment: and how can I create a textfile sir?

Comment: Exactly the same way you did it in your code. Just _try_ something, before asking someone else. `tsv` is the string that contains the entire file at the end of this snippet, which you would’ve found out, just by running this script in the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`).

Comment: let me try this sir thnx for the help by the way sir the join did not go to new line

Comment: I mean sir the `\n` did not create a new line in text file

Comment: Probably because you’re using the Windows line endings. Try `\r\n` instead.

Comment: TYSM sir my only problem here now is how can I make it a text file

Comment: yes sir but it didnt download the file instead lead me to another page.

Comment: Oh, right. For txt files, `window.location.href` isn’t the right approach, because the browser handles this differently. But it is possible to download files of any type, automatically.